# Ion pair definintion in chemistry

Tags: solutions

I read in the journal of organic chemistry:

> A less striking, but nonetheless significant, attenuation of the reactivity of phenyl selenide anion can be achieved by varying the counterion and/or the relative degree of ***solvation of the ion pair***. For example, when valerolactone (**3**) is allowed to reflux with sodium phenyl selenide in THF/HMPA for $3\,\mathrm{h}$, one obtains an $85\,\%$ yield of the $\unicode[Times]{x3C9}$-phenylselenenyl carboxylic acid 4.

My question is what is the meaning of the bolded expression (*solvation of the ion pair*) above?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] and visit the [help] for questions about the site. I have improved the formatting of your post, more details can also be found in the [help]. As for the question you are asking: An ion pair is merely a pair of ions (i.e. two). They can be in solution and are there *solvated* by the solvent.

Comment: see also **[ion pair](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.I03231)** in the IUPAC _Compendium of Chemical Terminology_ (Gold Book)

Answer (score 2):

As already said, *ion pair* is a pair of two ions like NaCl. When the pair separates completely into its constituent ions in the solvent (like Na<sup>+</sup> & Cl<sup>-</sup> in water), it is called dissociation.

After dissociation, if the solvent associates itself and surrounds the ions like this-
[image: Sodium ion surrounded by water molecules]

(Sodium ion surrounded by water molecules), it is called **Solvation**.
Solvation stabilises the compound and makes it either more reactive or less reactive.

Comment: Could the ion form a complex with the water molecules?